# What would happen in a case of a hung parliament and no one gained a majority?

Tags: election, united-kingdom

What would happen if say all parties refused to form a coalition with the party with the most seats, which then resulted them not gaining a majority of 326 seats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conservative minority government would form.

It would be the conservative party forming the government, as they have the most seats, but it would be a minority as they would have fewer than 326 seats. To pass bills, they would rely on the support of other parties on a bill-by-bill basis.

Comment: For the benefit of readers from a far future where the Conservatives are no longer the largest party, it might be worth clarifying that the largest party in a hung parliament typically gets the first attempt at forming a government.

Answer (score 3):

A majority government is not necessary for conservatives and Theresa May to remain in power. They simply wouldn't be able to pass laws on their own anymore which presents problems, but doesn't really mean anything in terms of a different leader.

Most probably the Tories will form a 'working arrangement' with the DUP in Ireland who share similar beliefs and policies. This will push them past the majority line and allow them to pass laws.

It is important to note though that this is not the same as a coalition.